# How convert sequential numerical processing of Cassandra table data to parallel in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We are doing some mathematical modelling on data from Cassandra table using the spark cassandra connector and the execution is currently sequential to get the output. How do you parallelize this for faster execution?

I'm new to Spark and I tried a few things but I'm unable understand how to use tabular data in map , groupby, reduceby functions. If someone can help explain (with some code snippets) how to parrellize tabular data, it will be really helpful.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf



class SparkExample(sparkSession: SparkSession, pathToCsv: String) {
  private val sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext
  sparkSession.stop()
  val conf = new SparkConf(true)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.0.1")                           
  .setAppName("cassandra").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


 def testExample(): Unit = {




val KNMI_rdd = sc.cassandraTable ("dbks1","knmi_w")


val Table_count = KNMI_rdd.count()
val KNMI_idx = KNMI_rdd.zipWithIndex
val idx_key = KNMI_idx.map{case (k,v) => (v,k)}

var i = 0
var n : Int = Table_count.toInt


println(Table_count)

for ( i  <- 1 to n if i < n) {
  println(i)


  val Row = idx_key.lookup(i)

  println(Row)


  val firstRow = Row(0)



  val yyyy_var = firstRow.get[Int]("yyyy")
  val mm_var = firstRow.get[Double]("mm")
  val dd_var = firstRow.get[Double]("dd")
  val dr_var = firstRow.get[Double]("dr")
  val tg_var = firstRow.get[Double]("tg")
  val ug_var = firstRow.get[Double]("ug")
  val loc_var = firstRow.get[String]("loc")



  val pred_factor = (((0.15461 * tg_var) + (0.8954 * ug_var)) / ((0.0000451 * dr_var) + 0.0004487))




  println(yyyy_var,mm_var,dd_var,loc_var)
  println(pred_factor)

 }

 }
}

  //test data

// loc | yyyy | mm | dd | dr  | tg  | ug
//-----+------+----+----+-----+-----+----
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  1 |  35 |   5 | 84
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  2 |  76 |  34 | 74
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  3 |  46 |  33 | 85
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  4 |  35 |   1 | 84
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  5 |  29 |   0 | 93
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  6 |  32 |  25 | 89
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  7 |  42 |  23 | 89
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  8 |  68 |  75 | 92
// AMS | 2019 |  1 |  9 |  98 |  42 | 86
// AMS | 2019 |  1 | 10 |  92 |  12 | 76
// AMS | 2019 |  1 | 11 |  66 |   0 | 71
// AMS | 2019 |  1 | 12 |  90 |  56 | 85
// AMS | 2019 |  1 | 13 |  83 | 139 | 90
```

**Edit 1:** 
I tired using map function and I'm able to calculate the mathematical computations, how do I add keys in front of these values which is defined by WeatherId?

```
            case class Weather( loc: String, yyyy: Int, mm: Int, dd: Int,dr: Double, tg: Double, ug: Double)
            case class WeatherId(loc: String, yyyy: Int, mm: Int, dd: Int)

                   val rows = dataset1
                                        .map(line => Weather(
                                              line.getAs[String]("loc"),
                                              line.getAs[Int]("yyyy"),
                                              line.getAs[Int]("mm"),
                                              line.getAs[Int]("dd"),
                                              line.getAs[Double]("dr"),
                                              line.getAs[Double]("tg"),
                                              line.getAs[Double]("ug")
                                                            ) )


                  val pred_factor   = rows
                                        .map(x => (( ((x.dr * betaz) + (x.tg * betay)) + (x.ug) * betaz)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**

Use a Dataframe/Dataset instead of an RDD.

The argument for DFs over RDDs is long but the short of it is that DFs and their structured alternative DS' outperform the low level RDDs.

With the spark-cassandra connector you can [configure input split size](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#example-changing-clusterkeyspace-level-properties) that dictate the size of partition size in spark, more partitions more parallelism.

```
val lastdf = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map(
    "table" -> "words",
    "keyspace" -> "test" ,
    "cluster" -> "ClusterOne",
    "spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb" -> 48 // smaller size = more partitions
    )
  ).load()
```

Comment: Thanks Lyuben, can you please check my followup question in edits above?